# Escape special characters for fputcsv();

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fputcsv

Is there an easy way to escape special characters, double quotes and multiple spaces for **fputcsv()**? In short with a lot of regex i get data from a PDF and i build my array. Inside the array there are no html tags with the exception of **<br>** tag. Now the problem is that i have to escape chars like these:

```
Èàèìòù"\'       <br>
```

This is the messy output that i have now:

```
&lt;br&gt; instead of <br>
� instead of È, ò, à, ', "
Lot of ������� where there are multiple spaces which i don't want
```

I'm using this code:

```
$fichier = 'file.csv';
header("Content-Type: text/csv;charset=UTF-8" );
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$fichier\"" );
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$fp= fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach ($output as $fields)
{
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
exit();
```

Tryed with array_map and many other functions with no success. I'm sure that it should be a simple question of charset encoding but it seems that content type UTF-8 is not working at all.

Comment: Use this link.. this should answer your questions
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php